# How to initialize N named, empty data frames into a list in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to initialize N named, empty data frames that have X rows and Y columns in each and put them in a list. I will fill them later by adding computed vectors. It’s a newbie question I know, but how does one do that? For example:

```
my.names <- c("G", "H", "J")
N <- 3
my.list <- ???  ## how?
```

(edited in light of replies ...) My reason for this approach is I have a big loop that creates N vectors each time through the loop. I need to save these results each iteration. I planned to do something like:

```
for(i in 1:N) my.list[[i]] <- my.vec[i]
```

on each pass in the loop. A 3D data frame or matrix would also do the same thing.

Comment: Possibly `my.list <- lapply(seq_len(N), function(x, nr = 4, nc = 5) {
  data.frame(matrix(,nrow=nr, ncol=nc))
})`

Comment: You should not do this, but rather should use a completely different approach. E.g., maybe you should create the data.frames when you have the "computed vectors". Hard to tell without more details.

Comment: Please look at me edit above. I may not have the best approach to my problem.

Comment: In light of your edit, I think a three-dimensional array (similar to a `matrix`) is a good way to go. I've added a couple lines of code to my answer to illustrate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you want to initialize a three-dimensional `array` instead?

```
myarr <- array(,dim=c(3,5,10))
for (j in 1:5) for (k in 1:10) myarr[,j,k] <- rnorm(3)
```

---

**List of empty data.frames.** I don't think there's a good reason to initialize a list of data.frames, but here's how it would be done:

An "empty" data.frame is created by `data.frame()`:

```
setNames(replicate(3,data.frame()),my.names)
# $G
# data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

# $H
# data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

# $J
# data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

A data.frame with rows and columns must have some values, for example `NA`:

```
nr  <- 4
nc  <- 4
ndf <- length(my.names)
setNames(replicate(ndf,as.data.frame(matrix(,nr,nc)),simplify=FALSE),my.names)
```

Comment: Thanks, Frank. I think your “myarr” solution with the array is the best solution for me, not a list of data frames. Not sure why the quotes don’t work.

Comment: @Ernie Glad it works, I'll rearrange the answer to put that at the top. I don't know why the quotes didn't work either...maybe they were formatted by MS Word to be curvy or something.